# How to add a JPanel to a JFrame

Tags: jframe, jpanel

I want to know what is the correct syntax for adding a JPanel that covers the entire JFrame.

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
package frame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame Frame = new JFrame("My Window");
    Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Frame.setVisible(true);
    Frame.setSize(320, 240);
    Frame.setResizable(false);
    Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //Thanks in advance
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
package frame;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame Frame = new JFrame("My Window");
Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Frame.setSize(320, 240);
Frame.setResizable(false);
Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
panel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    myPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("My window");
    jf.setVisible(true);

    jf.getContentPane().add(myPanel);
```

For more info you should read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).